# Is there any way to view the source code of how the AUTO mode of the cursor works in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I need to find out how the AUTO mode (flash.ui.MouseCursor.AUTO) of the cursor works and what code controls the cursor display depending on what object it is hovering over. Is there a way to view this code?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `flash.ui.MouseCursor` is part of the FlashPlayer API which is not open source.

What, specifically, do you need to know about how it works? You may be able to deduce general functionality by observing it in action.

Comment: I need to know when it becomes an I-beam. I have selectable static text fields in my project and when I try to detect them on MOUSE_MOVE or MOUSE_OVER, it doesn't work. But the cursor still changes to I-beam when I hover the mouse over those text fields. Therefore it can detect them somehow.

Comment: textField.buttonMode = true; textField.mouseChildren = false; should fix your events

Comment: I can't set properties of those text fields. Static text doesn't support instance names.

Answer (score 0):

[StaticText](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StaticText.html) inherits from [DisplayObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html) it is not an [InteractiveObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html). `InteractiveObject` is the class that adds (among other things) mouse interfactions.

Take a look at the documentation that I linked to for each class. Notice that in the properties sections for `StaticText` and `DisplayObject` there are no `mouseEnabled`, `mouseChildren`, or `buttonMode` properties as you have already observed. Also note that in the events section that these classes do not dispatch mouse events. These things are only possible if the class extends `InteractiveObject`.

The assumption here is that this is an optimization made by the Flash Player team. If you need text that will dispatch mouse events, you're going to need to use a TextField or some other class that extends `InteractiveObject` (use TLF text, put your `StaticText` inside a `Sprite` or `MovieClip`, etc.)

Comment: But when you make static text selectable, it becomes the TextField class, which should behave differently from the StaticText class.

Comment: @user2056564 I just learned something :) It's strange: when I made it selectable, it still showed up as static text in the properties pane... But then I wrote some code to test what type of object it was, and you're right. When it's selectable, the object added to the display list is a TextField. I'm curious and am going to look further... PS: I normally don't use Flash CS6 (just pure AS3 and Flex), so this is new and interesting :)

Comment: @user2056564 Well, this is just strange. Wrote more code to check on properties of the static text that is selectable, and everything seems to indicate that it should fire mouse events (hasEventListener(), mouseEnabled, etc.). But it just doesn't. There must be some optimization going on under the hood for stuff that is "static text" (not referring to the class name). Since making a static text selectable means the actual object on the display list is a TextField, I see no harm in just changing it to "dynamic text" to get the mouse events -- you're not using more memory or cpu. Thoughts?

Comment: Take a look at this http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d8e.html
The first note there says: In the Flash authoring tool, if you choose the selectable option on a static text field, the text field that is exported and placed on the display list is a regular, dynamic text field. 
Also I've found this article about the StaticText class
http://alexgblog.com/?p=3